# Functions suddenly require 'sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs'

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, function, code-behind

I'm doing final debugging on an asp.net project. My functions in codebehind are all simple, and most don't take any arguments. So for example, I log users in with a function that looks like this:

```
Sub LogInUser()

    (my code)

End Sub
```

These are called from the associated .aspx pages, usually with buttons. This has worked fine for weeks. Suddenly this morning, all my pages are giving me the error:

```
BC30408: Method 'Public Sub SearchAndChangePage()' does not have 
the same signature as delegate 'Delegate Sub EventHandler
(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)'.
```

I added those default arguments to my functions and they started working again. I guess I can go through my entire application and do that, and monkey around with the ones that take other arguments, but can anyone tell me why my application would suddenly behave that way? I really hate mysteries with my code that I can't resolve, even if I figure out how to work around them.

One thing, I've moved the .axpx and .aspx.vb files from my local development environment (in a 'solution' folder) and onto a server. But they were working fine on the server up until this morning.

Comment: Is `SearchAndChangePage` registered for the click event of some button?

Comment: are you using that method as an event handler?

Comment: @ChrisHardie, I'm afraid I'm not sure that that means - I'm working through a tutorial right now, but the upshot is that I have an .aspx page with a button, a codebehind with the sub, and that's about all I know. Are you talking about something I'm inheriting or importing at the top of the code file? I haven't changed any of that. It just started acting this way out of the blue.

Comment: @Steve, not sure method are you referring to. I just have an asp button on my .aspx page, a function in my code file, and that's it. Sorry to be such a noob.

Comment: In case anyone else reads this, my top line on the .aspx page is: <%@ Page Title="" Language="vb" CodeFile="index.aspx.vb" MasterPageFile="Site.Master" Inherits="CodeBehind" %>

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like you have turned `Options Strict On`, so VB.NET is no longer allowing you to get away with murder.

In reality, your subs like `SearchAndChangePage` should always have had the `object sender, EventArgs e` signature, but you were able to get away with not having that signature.

However you did it, you're programming like a professional now - this is the right way to do things, and you won't make as many mistakes without being told about them.

Comment: I just knew someone would say that. I think you're right because it also found another syntax error that it forced me to fix, but I know about that one. Thanks, I'll muddle through with the tutorials.

Comment: Option Explicit On; Option Strict On; Option Infer Off.  The way Programming was meant to be!